# Self and mutual capacitance

Tags: capacitance

Consider having a positively charged plate with charge +Q and potential at surface +V. Then, its self capacitance equals Q/V. Now, i have a similar plate with charge -Q and potential -V. The plates are to act as a mutual capacitor. The mutual capacitance equals Q/V-(-V) =Q/2V, i.e the capacitance decreases. But, i have read it many times that mutual capacitance is more than the self capacitance. Where i am wrong here? Thanks in advance for clearing my doubts.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/68406/why-do-capacitors-lose-capacitance-in-series/68408#68408

Answer (score 0):

The mutual capacitance depends on if you have the two capacitors in parallel or in series. In parallel, the capacitance would increase and yield $2 Q/V$, but if they are in series, the result would be the one you obtained, $Q/2V$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misusing the terminology. $Q/V$ is the mutual capacitance for a pair of parallel plates. It is commonly abbreviated to simply "capacitance".

When you introduce another plate, you can do so either in series or in parallel (in electrical terms). When introduced in series you will have three plates so 6 surfaces. When you connect a voltage source the charges on the 6 surfaces will be

$(0,-Q)\;\;\;\;(Q,-Q)\;\;\;\;(Q,0)$

Thus you have a total charge of $Q$ which moved from the 1st plate to the third. The voltage between the first two plates is the same as if the third plate were not there and we had charge $Q$, so it is $V_{12} = Q/C$ where $C$ is the capacitance of just one pair of plates. The voltage $V_{23}$ between the other two plates is also $Q/C$ (because, again, the surface charge is the same, which leads to the same electric field, so as long as the spacings are of equal length then we get the same voltage). So the total voltage is
$$
V_{\rm tot} = V_{12} + V_{23} = 2 \frac{Q}{C}
$$
for a total charge of $Q$ which has moved off the first plate and onto the third. Hence the total capacitance is
$$
C_{\rm tot} = \frac{Q}{V_{\rm tot}} = \frac{C}{2}.
$$

If instead the extra plate is joined to one of the others so as to extend its surface area then you have changed the area. To make equal area plates you have to then do the same to the other plate. Now you have effectively just two plates but with larger area, so the capacitance goes up (for any given plate separation).